# finding control in Page.Controls

Tags: asp.net

When I pass `Page.Controls` to a method, is there a way to get to the specific control by its name or any other quick way? As opposed to iterating through the `ControlCollection` like so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4.aspx
?

Edit:
Sorry I should be more clear. I have an instance of a class that performs database work (such as inserting form data). From the codebehind of an .aspx page I am passing `Page.Controls` to the method of that class instance. The method receives this as `ControlCollection`. Inside that method there is no such method as `Page.FindControl`. However, I can iterate though this collection. But any faster way?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why should you pass web-specific objects to a data-related method? Bad separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

try this for find specific control on the `Page`

```
Control control = Page.FindControl["ControlId"]
```

After this you can `cast` this control as of your original `control` like this

```
TextBox textbox=(TextBox)control;
```

If you want to find specific control from ControlCollection then you can use `Linq` like (I am taking example of `TextBox`) this

```
Control myControl = myControlCollection.OfType<TextBox>().Where(a => a.ID == "controlId").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Great answer! But I'm going to follow John Saunders advice and keep the web objects in the .aspx/codebehind. I will collect data in the codebehind and pass in to the data-processing class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.FindControl("lblControl")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of control you want to find you could do something like this:

```
Control ctrl = FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Page.FindControl method is ok if controls are on "same level" but more often than not, Controls are buried within other controls. Unfortunately, odds are you need to recursively search through all controls in a given page. Here is a piece of code I use to find control(s) by its given id value...

```
string g_Error = string.Empty;
List<Control> _infos = new List<Control>();
_infos = ProcessControls(_infos, Page, "info_");
...
    public List<Control> ProcessControls(List<Control> MatchControls, Control controls, string FieldKey)
    {
        try
        {
            //get a recusive listing of all existing controls for reference
            foreach (Control cControl in controls.Controls)
            {
                if (cControl.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    //recusive call
                    MatchControls = ProcessControls(MatchControls, cControl, FieldKey);
                }
                //field rules
                //must contain Fieldkey to be collected (i.e. control id = FirstName where the FieldKey is "Name")
                //so first, loop through and collect controls with FieldKey
                if (cControl != null)
                {
                    if (cControl.ClientID.Contains(FieldKey))
                    {
                        MatchControls.Add(cControl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            g_Error = ex.ToString();
        }
        return MatchControls;
    }
```